# Trying to wake my Mac using Apple / Power Manager Script triggered by Folder Actions

Tags: mac, applescript, automator, sleep-wake, power-management

I've been trying to tweak the following script to achieve this. (original script)

```
tell application "Power Manager Scripting"

tell workshop

    set myEvent to make new event with properties {id:"myWakeEvent", name:"Wake up for work"}

    -- Create a daily trigger
    make new trigger daily at front of triggers of myEvent with properties {seconds from midnight:(8 * 60 * 60),availability:wake up, days: [Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday]}

end tell

-- Deploy the event
tell Event Store to store these events myEvent

-- Clean up
tell the workshop to empty

end tell
```

I'm trying to use the Power Manager's  "myWakeEvent" or some kind of WakeEvent to trigger my Mac to wake up. My intention is to place this script into a Folder Action then go from there.  I've tried bypassing all date and time properties but don't know how to structure to create just the simple trigger.

Answer (score 1):

This script works with the latest [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/), once the first line is changed to read:

```
tell application "Power Manager"
```

[image: Script Editor]

[image: Power Manager]

See [Power Manager's AppleScript documentation](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/guide/v4/applescript/) for more examples.

If you need help with Power Manager, please contact support@dssw.co.uk. We are be better able to help via e-mail.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation @Graham Miln and I appreciate the support. I was trying to pick this script apart to make, just a trigger to wake my mac.  My intention is to send an email to a folder and have that email trigger this script to wake my mac via Folder Actions. If that will even work. I just could not figure out how to make a "wake" command. From what I read Power Management was the only way to go.

Comment: Will your Mac be asleep when the e-mail arrives?

Comment: Yes it will, and I've been thinking about this for some many hours now that I forgot just that,, it will be asleep and won't even acknowledge the email until it wakes.. I think I've wasted your time man, sorry..

Comment: No problem; good to explore the idea. If you want to try an approach that has your Mac waking at intervals to check for e-mail, that should be possible.

Comment: I'm actually trying to create commands for my Amazon Echo. I've got it to sleep, restart, shutdown, launch apps, but was trying to find a way to wake it. Can you think of any service or method that would trigger the system to wake short of a scheduled wake or button press?

Comment: The traditional way to wake a sleeping Mac, without a schedule, is using a Wake On LAN (WOL) network packet. Consider [asking a new question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to see what others have tried.

Comment: Yeah, that's the only other method I could think of. Thanks again!!